# Let $f (x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f (x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If $f (x)$ has no multiple roots
and $f (x_1 )f (x_2 ) < 0,$ where $x_1 < x_2$ are real numbers. Then

(i) $f$ has exactly one root in $(x_1 , x_2 ).$

(ii) $f$ has an even number of roots in $(x_1 , x_2 ).$

(iii) $f$ has an odd number of roots in $(x_1 , x_2 ).$

(iv) None of the above.

If we replace the polynomial f by a continuous function $g$, what can be said?

By Bolzano's theorem I can say $f$ has at least one root say $c$ on $(x_1,x_2)$, if there is another root $d\ne c$ then $f'(p)=0$. Is there any connection between roots of derivative of $f$ and $f$ does not have multiple root? So basically other options can be solved easily if we can solve (i),
I dont know what can be said if we replace any other continuous function. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial with no multiple roots changes sign at every root (and of course nowhere else). Therefore (iii) is correct. Note that (i) need not be correct, for example there can be three roots.

For general continuous functions, do you have a notion of single vs. multiple root at all? Or can we conclude at all that the number of zeroes between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is finite? (Of course the intermediate value theorem still gives us *at least* one root)

Comment: why odd i do not understand

Comment: @BicycleTheif If there are no multiple roots, at every root $f' \neq 0$. Thus either $f' >0$ in which case $f$ is increasing near that root or the opposite. In both situations, at the root $f$ changes sign.... The number of roots is then the number of sign changes in the interval... And after 2 sign changes, the function has the same sign, same applies for an even number of changes.